# mongodb $sum all values in object with variable key name

Tags: mongodb, hadoop, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

we have the following document

```
{
    "_id" : "F80BBEDE6395",
    "up" : {
        "10" : NumberLong(1916327),
        "11" : NumberLong("4557798933"),
        "12" : NumberLong(1057250763),
        "13" : NumberLong(10167577),
        "14" : NumberLong(9464393),
        "15" : NumberLong(10082616),
        "16" : NumberLong(9982689),
        "17" : NumberLong(8612066),
        "18" : NumberLong(193879404),
        "19" : NumberLong("4692628921"),
        "20" : NumberLong(541674158),
        "21" : NumberLong(10482839),
        "22" : NumberLong(9671272)
    },
    "down" : {
        "10" : NumberLong(1880514),
        "11" : NumberLong("19698709594"),
        "12" : NumberLong("28850509901"),
        "13" : NumberLong(10073361),
        "14" : NumberLong(9283009),
        "15" : NumberLong(9533924),
        "16" : NumberLong(9605101),
        "17" : NumberLong(1398871165),
        "18" : NumberLong("34124867465"),
        "19" : NumberLong("180468996228"),
        "20" : NumberLong("18472208011"),
        "21" : NumberLong(10066752),
        "22" : NumberLong(9288118)
    },
    "monthUp" : NumberLong("11113611958"),
    "monthDown" : NumberLong("283073893143")
}
```

up and down are objects, one by day with a counter (day 10 of month, day 11, and so on).

The problem we get is how to in an update, sum all "up" values to "monthUp" and all "down" values to "monthDown"

In this example, the monthUp and monthDown are not ok, since both are not the sum of up / down objects.

This document is build from a hadoop process that updates every item on "up" and "down", since the hadoop job updates the document and we want to avoid a new job to make the "monthDown" and "monthUp" sum, will be very effective and useful for us to do the sum on the same update operation.

Thanks in advance